# Optimising Rspec Tests to Avoid Repeating Complex Setup Proceedures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So here's my problem:

I am writing unit tests for my Rails models and I have a whole set of examples that each require the same setup in order to run. If I'm not mistaken, the usual way to set things up the same way for multiple RSpec tests is to use a before(:each) block, like this:

```
describe Model do
  before(:each) do
    # Complex setup
  end
  # Examples
end
```

Unfortunately the set of examples which needs this setup is starting to get rather large, and completing this complex setup proceedure for each and every test takes a long time. I tried doing this:

```
describe Model do
  before(:all) do
    # Complex setup
  end
  # Examples
end
```

But this method doesn't roll back my setup though after I'm done with it, which causes problems in later tests. What I really want is to do something like this:

```
describe Model do
  around(:all) do |examples|
    transaction do
      # Complex setup
      examples.run
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
  # Examples
end
```

RSpec doesn't currently support an around(:all) hook however. Any ideas?

Comment: Follow up question: [Rolling back Transactions Without using a Block](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12675128/1157054)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would just be to use an `after(:all)` block to clean up after your tests.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll probably end up doing something similar to that. A good portion of my setup process relys on external code though (I'm using FactoryGirl), so cleaning things up that way may be a bit complicated if I do it manually.