# Rolling back Transactions Without using a Block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

> **Note:** This is a follow up question to [*Optimising Rspec Tests to Avoid Repeating Complex Setup Proceedures*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12646871/1157054)

For reasons that are outside the scope of this question (see the note above), I want to be able to start a Rails database transaction and then rollback that transaction in a different scope. E.g:

```
def before_callback
  start_transaction # Start the transaction
  # Create/Update some records
end

def after_callback
  rollback_transaction # Rollback changes from before_callback and do_stuff
end

def do_stuff
  before_callback
  # Do some stuff
  after_callback
end

do_stuff
```

I realize this is a contrived example which could be resolved easily with `transaction do .. end` and a little refactoring, but in the context have in mind `do_stuff` is part of an external plugin that I really don't want to mess with. Is there a way to do something similar to what I just described in Rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a crude quick-and-dirty solution you could just execute the required SQL commands directly on the database connection:

```
def start_transaction
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("BEGIN")
end

def rollback_transaction
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ROLLBACK")
end
```

Also looking at the source of the `transaction` method might give you some ideas on how to approach this in a more refined manner.

(You can find it in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::DatabaseStatements` in `lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb`)

Comment: Will that "quick and dirty" solution break if other transactions exist  between `start_transaction` and `end_transaction`?

Comment: That depends on the database, but AFAIK most engines support it. They might not necessarily create real nested transactions, though. (i.e. they just ignore the inner commands).

Comment: Just to put the third method for transactions out there: `def end_transaction
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("COMMIT")
    end`

Comment: It doesn't work with sqlite3 -- you get `SQLite3::SQLException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction: begin transaction`. There's probably a workaround with [savepoints](https://sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html), but not a database-agnostic one.